# How to access a custom serializer when handling ngrx router default actions

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular-routing, ngrx-router-store

I'm using a custom serializer with `@ngrx/router-store`

```
export interface CustomSerializer {
  url: string;
  params: Params;
  queryParams: Params;
  data: Data;
  showFilter: boolean;
}
```

I've done the basic setup and the store is tracking my routes using the serializer type as expected.

I'd like to be able to access the custom type in an effect which triggers from built-in actions, like this

```
test$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(routerNavigatedAction),
    tap(({ payload }) => {
      console.log('filter?:' + payload.routerState.showFilter); <-- not allowed by typescript
    })
  ), { dispatch: false }
);
```

but `payload` which is provided by `routerNavigatedAction` is of type `RouterNavigatedPayload<SerializedRouterStateSnapshot>`.  `SerializedRouterStateSnapshot` only knows about `root` and `url` and knows nothing of `showFilter`, even though it's there at runtime

[image: debugging breakpoint]

(debugging breakpoint before tap()):

Is there a way for me to tie in to the core routing events and configure the infrastructure to return my custom serializer type? If not, is there a 'good' way to get at that showFilter property in my effect? I know I can use a selector to get the data strongly typed from the store, but I would prefer to use the payload which is already provided by the effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this what you are looking for

```
test$ = createEffect(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<RouterNavigatedAction<CustomSerializer>>(routerNavigatedAction),
    tap(({ payload }) => {
      console.log('filter?:' + payload.routerState.showFilter);
    })
  ), { dispatch: false }
);
```

Comment: I tip my hat to you, good man. Is this documented somewhere and I'm just bad at Google?

Comment: Sorry, Josh, this is how I have configured it in my job, I never looked for it. GL